# How do I mention someone in tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I’m trying to mention myself as a test, but it’s not working. Can anyone help?

```
api.update_status(api.get_user(myaccountusername))
```

Comment: Please show a working piece of code you wrote yet about your trial to solve this problem, and give more specific error messages or details you would like help about. So we can copy paste and reproduce, so it is easier to answer your question.
See MRE here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the mentions (using the user screen_name) as part of the tweet

```
api.update_status(f'@user1 @user2  check this out')
```

The call to `api.get_user(myaccountusername)` returns the full User object

```
User(_api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x101cb39a0>, _json={'id': 3300744875, 
'id_str': '3300744875', 'name': 'Beppe Catanese', 'screen_name': 
'beppecatanese', 'location': 'Amsterdam, The Netherlands', 'profile_location': 
None, 'description': 
etc.. 
etc...
```